# Resolving linkage errors when building Rust crate with multiple dependencies on libcuda

Tags: c, rust, cuda, linker, ffi

I have a crate named `foo`.

`foo` depends on the crate [cudarc](https://docs.rs/cudarc/latest/cudarc/) which is a sys crate for `libcuda` (the cuda driver api).

`foo` also depends on a different another C library (`libsmctrl`). The C implementation imports and makes calls to `libcuda`. I created a sys crate for this library called [rs-smctrl](https://github.com/atomicapple0/rs-smctrl).

I can build `cudarc` and `rs-smctrl` individually. Additionally, I can build `foo` if it contains strictly one of these dependencies. However, when I try to use both crates at the same time, the linker complains.

Ideally, I want foo to statically link to `libsmctrl` and dynamically link to `libcuda`.

I recieve the following linking error when building `foo`:

```
...
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: /h/bez/work/rs-smctrl/target/debug/deps/librs_smctrl-ee6526e2da5cab52.rlib(libsmctrl.o): in function `setup_g_sm_control_10':
          /h/bez/work/rs-smctrl/src/libsmctrl.c:53: undefined reference to `cudbgReportDriverApiErrorFlags'
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
          
  = note: some `extern` functions couldn't be found; some native libraries may need to be installed or have their path specified
  = note: use the `-l` flag to specify native libraries to link
  = note: use the `cargo:rustc-link-lib` directive to specify the native libraries to link with Cargo (see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#cargorustc-link-libkindname)

error: could not compile `rs-smctrl` (bin "rs-smctrl") due to previous error
```

```
# `build.rs` for `rs-smctrl`
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=cuda");

    let src = ["src/libsmctrl.c"];
    let mut builder = cc::Build::new();
    let build = builder
        .files(src.iter())
        .include("/usr/local/cuda/include")
        .flag("-Wno-unused-parameter")
        .flag("-Wno-parentheses")
        .flag("-Wno-sign-compare");
    build.compile("libsmctrl");
}
```

The below works if I comment out the `cudarc` dependency!

```
# `Cargo.toml` for `foo`:
[package]
name = "foo"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
cudarc = { version="0.9.15", features=["std", "driver"], default-features = false }
rs-smctrl = { git = "https://github.com/atomicapple0/rs-smctrl.git" }
```

```
# `main.rs` for `foo`
fn main() {
    unsafe { rs_smctrl::libsmctrl_set_global_mask(0) };
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Comment: The missing function isn’t part of libcuda

Comment: `~/$ nm -gD /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1 | grep cudbgReportDriverApiErrorFlags

0000000001c774d8 B cudbgReportDriverApiErrorFlags`
Its a valid symbol on my cuda version at least.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of `libsmctrl`. Please pull and use a newer version of the library. Commit [3ee97459](http://rtsrv.cs.unc.edu/cgit/cgit.cgi/libsmctrl.git/commit/?id=3ee974590403730f2fea911a2574d335cedc4fab) of `libsmctrl` should work around this issue, which originates from a missing symbol in a commonly-distributed stub of `libcuda.so`.

Starting with CUDA 11.8, the `libcuda.so` stub distributed with the CUDA SDK ( in `/usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/stubs/libcuda.so`) started omitting the symbol `cudbgReportDriverApiErrorFlags`, despite this symbol still being part of the actual CUDA library as installed by the driver (in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so`). The absence of the symbol causes `libsmctrl.so` to fail to build when linked against the `libcuda.so` stub. Rather than forcing everyone to link against the full library, `libsmctrl.so` has been fixed by doing an online lookup of the symbol via `dlsym()` rather than relying on the linker.